# Multiple PHP MySQL simpler queries vs one single more complex query,

Tags: php, mysql

Should I do single more complex MySQL query or multiple simpler queries with PHP?

For example

Simpler queries:

```
UPDATE image SET profile = 0 WHERE user_id = 1;

UPDATE image SET profile = 1 WHERE user_id = 1 AND id = 10;
```

One single more complex query:

```
UPDATE image
    SET profile = CASE id WHEN 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    WHERE user_id = 1;
```

1: What is fastest and most efficient?

2: What is considered to be best practice, or preferred method?

Comment: such a question has been asked many times before, please do some research before asking on SO

Comment: I can't think of a reason to use the 1-st option in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One single query is fastest and most efficient

> Besides the IF statement, MySQL also provides an alternative
>   conditional statement called MySQL CASE. The MySQL CASE statement
>   makes the code more readable and efficient. See more details...
>   http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/